# Select Box squished and elongated in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, drop-down-menu

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bk5hfga/2/) for the rest of the code but I attached my style css below

In Chrome they look like this
[image: Chrome]

In Internet Explorer they look like this [image: Internet Explorer]

And in Firefox they look like this [image]

Not exactly sure what the issue is and how to fix it

And here is my style css

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5;
}
body {
    font: normal .80em'trebuchet ms', arial, sans-serif;
    background: #F5F5EE;
    color: #555;
}
p {
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}
img {
    border: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #362C20;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}
h1, h2, h3 {
    font: normal 170%'century gothic', arial;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
    color: #000;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 160%;
    padding: 9px 0 5px 0;
    color: #009FBC;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 140%;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
}
h4, h6 {
    color: #009FBC;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
    font: normal 110% arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
h5, h6 {
    color: #888;
    font: normal 95% arial;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    padding: 0 0 15px 0;
}
a, a:hover {
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #AEB002;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
blockquote {
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 10px 20px 0 20px;
    border: 1px solid #E5E5DB;
    background: #FFF;
}
ul {
    margin: 2px 0 22px 17px;
}
ul li {
    list-style-type: circle;
    margin: 0 0 6px 0;
    padding: 0 0 4px 5px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
ol {
    margin: 8px 0 22px 20px;
}
ol li {
    margin: 0 0 11px 0;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.center {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
#main, #logo, #menubar, #site_content, #footer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#header {
    background: #323534 url(back.png) repeat-x;
    height: 177px;
}
#logo {
    width: 880px;
    position: relative;
    height: 140px;
    background: transparent;
}
#logo #logo_text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
}
#logo h1, #logo h2 {
    font: normal 300%'century gothic', arial, sans-serif;
    border-bottom: 0;
    text-transform: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 9px;
}
#logo_text h1, #logo_text h1 a, #logo_text h1 a:hover {
    padding: 22px 0 0 0;
    color: #FFF;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#logo_text h1 a .logo_colour {
    color: #E4EC04;
}
#logo_text a:hover .logo_colour {
    color: #FFF;
}
#logo_text h2 {
    font-size: 120%;
    padding: 4px 0 0 0;
    color: #999;
}
#menubar {
    width: 880px;
    height: 46px;
}
ul#menu {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
}
ul#menu li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 0 9px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 1px 2px 0 0;
    background: #5A5A5A url(tab.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
ul#menu li a {
    font: normal 100%'trebuchet ms', sans-serif;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 6px 35px 5px 28px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #5A5A5A url(tab.png) no-repeat 100% 0;
}
ul#menu li.selected a {
    height: 20px;
    padding: 6px 35px 5px 28px;
}
ul#menu li.selected {
    margin: 1px 2px 0 0;
    background: #00C6F0 url(tab_selected.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
ul#menu li.selected a, ul#menu li.selected a:hover {
    background: #00C6F0 url(tab_selected.png) no-repeat 100% 0;
    color: #FFF;
}
ul#menu li a:hover {
    color: #E4EC04;
}
#site_content {
    width: 880px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}
#sidebar_container {
    float: right;
    width: 224px;
}
.sidebar_top {
    width: 222px;
    height: 14px;
    background: transparent url(side_top.png) no-repeat;
}
.sidebar_base {
    width: 222px;
    height: 14px;
    background: url(side_base.png) no-repeat;
}
.sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 222px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 16px 0;
}
.sidebar_item {
    background: url(side_back.png) repeat-y;
    padding: 0 15px;
    width: 192px;
}
.sidebar li a.selected {
    color: #444;
}
.sidebar ul {
    margin: 0;
}
#content {
    text-align: left;
    width: 620px;
    padding: 0 0 0 5px;
    float: left;
}
#content ul {
    margin: 2px 0 22px 0px;
}
#content ul li, .sidebar ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    background: url(bullet.png) no-repeat;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 4px 25px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    font-family:'trebuchet ms', sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 28px 0 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: #3B3939 url(footer.png) repeat-x;
    color: #A8AA94;
}
#footer p {
    line-height: 1.7em;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}
#footer a {
    color: #A8AA94;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#footer a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.search {
    color: #5D5D5D;
    border: 1px solid #BBB;
    width: 134px;
    padding: 4px;
    font: 100% arial, sans-serif;
}
.form_settings {
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
.form_settings p {
    padding: 0 0 4px 0;
}
.form_settings span {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: left;
}
.form_settings input {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 225px;
    font: 100% arial;
    border: 1px solid #E5E5DB;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #47433F;
}
.form_settings .submit:hover {
    background: #00CAEE;
    color: #E4EC04;
}
.form_settings .submit {
    font: 100% arial;
    border: 0;
    width: 99px;
    margin: 0 0 0 212px;
    height: 33px;
    padding: 2px 0 3px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #3B3B3B;
    color: #FFF;
    -o-transition:color .2s ease-out, background .5s ease-in;
    -ms-transition:color .2s ease-out, background .5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:color .2s ease-out, background .5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition:color .2s ease-out, background .5s ease-in;
    /* ...and now for the proper property */
    transition:color .2s ease-out, background .5s ease-in;
}
.important-btn:hover {
    background: #8C1717;
}
.important-btn {
    font: 100% arial;
    border: 0;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 215px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 2px 0 3px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #52514F;
    color: #FFF;
    -o-transition:color .2s ease-out, background .5s ease-in;
    -ms-transition:color .2s ease-out, background .5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:color .2s ease-out, background .5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition:color .2s ease-out, background .5s ease-in;
    /* ...and now for the proper property */
    transition:color .2s ease-out, background .5s ease-in;
}
.regularbutton:hover {
    background: #00CAEE;
    color: #E4EC04;
}
.regularbutton {
    font: 100% arial;
    border: 0;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 212px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 2px 0 3px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #52514F;
    color: #FFF;
    -o-transition:color .2s ease-out, background .5s ease-in;
    -ms-transition:color .2s ease-out, background .5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:color .2s ease-out, background .5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition:color .2s ease-out, background .5s ease-in;
    /* ...and now for the proper property */
    transition:color .2s ease-out, background .5s ease-in;
}
.whattoput:hover {
    background: #00CAEE;
    color: #E4EC04;
}
.whattoput {
    font: 100% arial;
    border: 0;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 0px 0 0px 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #52514F;
    color: #FFF;
    -o-transition:color .2s ease-out, background .5s ease-in;
    -ms-transition:color .2s ease-out, background .5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:color .2s ease-out, background .5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition:color .2s ease-out, background .5s ease-in;
    /* ...and now for the proper property */
    transition:color .2s ease-out, background .5s ease-in;
}
.form_settings option {
    font: 100% arial;
    border: 0;
    width: 10px;
    margin: 5px 0 0 212px;
    height: 33px;
    padding: 2px 0 3px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #52514F;
    color: #FFF;
}
.form_settings select {
    font: 100% arial;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
    width: 140px;
}
.form_settings textarea {
    font: 100% arial;
    width: 225px;
}
.form_settings .checkbox {
    margin: 4px 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 14px;
    border: 0;
    background: none;
}
.separator {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #D9D5CF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
table {
    margin: 10px 0 30px 0;
}
table tr th, table tr td {
    background: #3B3B3B;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 7px 4px;
    text-align: left;
}
table tr td {
    background: #E5E5DB;
    color: #47433F;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
}
.hideother {
    display: none;
}
#banner {
    width: 100%;
    background: orange;
    height: 25px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#4F0002;
}
```

Comment: Do you use any plugin for select box ?

Comment: @JeevaJsb No plugins are used at all

Comment: Can you give any fiddler for this ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6bk5hfga/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.form_settings option {
    ...
    width: 10px;
    ...
}
```

is your culprit.

Chrome and IE don't honor most `option` styling (dag blast them), so it renders as the browser intends it to, but Firefox (it would seem) lets you mess it up all you want. And you have definitely messed it up with the `width: 10px;`. I would just recommend losing all of your `option` styles, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: I agree. Browser support is so bad for styling select boxes that if you really need a styled box you should use a third party script that creates a select box out of styleable divs and whatnot.

Comment: Yeah, and I don't think it'd be too hard to create one yourself. It'd be a fun challenge at least. You've got me wanting to try that now.

Comment: Select2 is a great jquery based option that also gives you the benefit of searching through options.